# Why Range.Range doesn't work as described in MS documentation

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range consisting from just one cell and I want to select it's subrange containing just first cell.

```
Private Sub test10()
  Dim rg1 As Range
  Dim rg2 As Range
  Set rg1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B1")
  With rg1
    Set rg2 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1))
  End With
  Debug.Print "rg1.Address: " & rg1.address 'prints $B$1
  Debug.Print "rg2.Address: " & rg2.address 'prints $C$1
End Sub
```

It should return actual range, but it shifts the range by one column. 
Why this doesn't work? It is almost the same as the example mentioned here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.range

Comment: It works if you do `Set rg2 = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1))` (minus the first dot). Don't ask me why. Possibly because you are in effect writing range(B1).range("B1") which is equivalent to C1.

Comment: The last example mentioned there is in fact wrong. If you run it you will see that it makes the font italic in `C3:E7` **not** `B2:D6`

Comment: @SJR Yeah, it works, providing that Sheet1 is ActiveSheet. Otherwise if fails.

Comment: Er, no it doesn't.

Comment: @SJR Ok, it works (I thought you meant the dot before Cells), but it returns the range from ActiveSheet instead of Sheet1

Comment: Once again, I think not! See below.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the last `debug.print` shows that the active sheet when the macro is run does not matter.

Activate any sheet before it is run and it will still return "Sheet1" because that is how `rg1` is defined.

```
Private Sub test10()

  Dim rg1 As Range
  Dim rg2 As Range

  'Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate 'uncommenting this line makes no difference as sheet is specified below in rg1
  Set rg1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B1")

  With rg1
    Set rg2 = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1))
  End With

  Debug.Print "rg1.Address: " & rg1.Address 'prints $B$1
  Debug.Print "rg2.Address: " & rg2.Address 'prints $C$1
  Debug.Print rg2.Parent.Name 'prints Sheet1

End Sub
```

Comment: Magic! Finally I must say, I don't understand how it works. When you remove the dot from Cells, cells refer to the active sheet. When you remove the dot from Range, range refers to what?

Comment: `Range` just sets a range, and doesn't need a sheet as it defined as the range from two cells which have an implicit sheet reference because of rg1. So you are defining a range which runs from sheet1.B1 to sheet1.B1. There is a question on SO which explains this but I can't find it atm.